# How to remove DataColumn from DataTable programmatically

Tags: c#, collections, datatable, datacolumn, datacolumncollection

I have a code

```
foreach (DataColumn dataTableCol in this.dataTable.Columns)
            {
                bool columnFound = false;
                foreach (GRTColumnView uiColumn in descriptor.UIColumns)
                {
                    if (dataTableCol.ColumnName.Equals(uiColumn.Name))
                    {
                        columnFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!columnFound)
                {
                    if (this.dataTable.Columns.Contains(dataTableCol.ColumnName))
                        this.dataTable.Columns.Remove(dataTableCol.ColumnName);
                }

            }
```

I want to remove some "things" from collection if they aren't found in another collection.

When I run the above program, I get

> *Iteration may not execute as collection was modified*

"Collection was modified" - Coz the remove must have been hit

**What is the way to achieve such a thing then ?**

What I can think of is make a note of all the "things" to remove and then

```
foreach( aThing in all_things_to_remove)
     remove_from_collection(aThing)
```

But above doesn't seem a good way to me, as I have to do another looping and am using extra memory

Comment: @Plutonix Like this ?   `for(inedx = this.dataTable.Columns.Count - 1 ; index >= 0 ; index++)`  or is there is better way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this specific case, where you're looping through a small collection containing a few columns, you can just create a new collection (via `ToList()`), so that you're not iterating over the same collection you're modifying:

```
foreach (var dataTableCol in dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList())
{
    ...

    dataTable.Columns.Remove(dataTableCol.ColumnName);
}
```

The recommended way, especially if the collection is large, is to enumerate backwards:

```
for (var i = dataTable.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    ...

    dataTable.Columns.Remove(dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case, as you said collection is small, but what if my collection was a large one ? Would there have been a way out to avoid copy ?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (dt.Columns.Contains("RecordID")){
                    dt.Columns.Remove("RecordID");
                    dt.AcceptChanges();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove items from a collection while enumerating it with the foreach loop. Make a copy of the collection using `Collection.ToArray()` and run you foreach on the copy and remove your item from the actual collection.

Since DataTable.Columns does not have  `ToArray` or `ToList` methods, you could use the `CopyTo()` method and copy the entire columns to a ColumnsArray.

If you do not want to create a copy, then you can use for loop instead of foreach loop. You could edit you code this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    bool columnFound = false;
    foreach (GRTColumnView uiColumn in descriptor.UIColumns)
    {
        if (dataTable.Columns[i].Name.Equals(uiColumn.Name))
        {
            columnFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!columnFound)
    {
        if (this.dataTable.Columns.Contains(dataTableCol.ColumnName))
            this.dataTable.Columns.Remove(dataTableCol.ColumnName);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, I know that from the error. I am asking a way out. And the way you are suggesting, I have already pointed similar approach in my question and that does not sound good to me

Answer (score 0):

the other way is lowering the index after removing column.

```
for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (datatable.Columns[i].ColumnName.Contains("Column"))
                {
                    datatable.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
```